# Segmentation fault with Haskell Z3 api

Tags: c, haskell, segmentation-fault, z3

I'm using Haskell with this Z3 package, which closely mirrors (and makes use of, via Haskell's foreign function interface) the C api: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/z3

I'm getting a segmentation fault, and have managed to reduce it to the following:

```
mainx = do
    print =<< intCheck [0..70]

intCheck :: [Int] -> IO [Int]
intCheck [] = return []
intCheck (x:xs) = 
    do
        checking <- evalZ3 $ checkImpact x
        print checking
        return =<< intCheck xs

checkImpact :: Int -> Z3 Result
checkImpact r  = do
    reset

    xSymb <- mkStringSymbol "x"
    x <- mkConst xSymb  =<< mkIntSort
    trace ("asserting = " ++ show r) assert =<< mkEq x x

    solverCheck
```

The output is:

```
asserting = 0
Sat
asserting = 1
Sat
asserting = 2
Sat
...[omitted]
asserting = 45
Sat
asserting = 46
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Usually, the last asserting is somewhere around 46, but it does vary between executions.  My best guess is that memory is not being freed properly (I can't figure out why it would halt at slightly different points otherwise), but I'm unsure if it's a problem with my recursion (in intCheck), or with the z3 api.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I would open a bug report in the haskell package, and let them deal with upstream if there's an issue

Comment: I've done that:
https://bitbucket.org/iago/z3-haskell/issues/12/possible-error-in-package
If iago replies there, and not here, I'll post an update.

Answer (score 0):

I see there is one spacing issue in the code you pasted (the alignment of `do`).  Please ensure that this is otherwise the code causing your issue.

I am unable to reproduce your issue:

```
% ghc so.hs -fforce-recomp && ./so 2>&1 | tail ; ghc --version ; z3 -version
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( so.hs, so.o )
Linking so ...
Sat
Sat
Sat
Sat
Sat
Sat
Sat
Sat
Sat
[]
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.3
Z3 version 4.4.1
```

Oh, and:

```
% ghc-pkg list z3
   z3-4.1.0
```

EDIT: Matching GHC and Z3 versions and I still can not reproduce the issue:

```
% LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib ghc so.hs -fforce-recomp && LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib ./so 2>&1 | tail ; ghc --version ; z3 -version
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( so.hs, so.o )
Linking so ...
Sat
Sat
Sat
Sat
Sat
Sat
Sat
Sat
Sat
[]
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.0.1
Z3 version 4.3.2
```

Comment: Sorry about that error- I had to reindent everything after copying and pasting to SO, and messed up that section (it's now fixed.)
We do have different versions of ghc (I'm on 8.0.1) and z3 (I'm on 4.4.2.)  Same version of the z3 haskell package though.
Did you run it with 0 to 70 (or some other larger number), and just cut down your output? I don't get the segment fault error when I use just [0..9].

Comment: I ran with 0..70, just your code with the indentation fixed.

Comment: Alright, well thanks for looking at it anyway.  I'm inclined to doubt it has to do with ghc, but I'll see if I can give it a shot with 7.10.3, just in case.

Comment: @Bill I have tried with GHC 8.0.1 and Z3 4.3.2 (commit `79326e24dfb9dff723d1ce64b3f50bcf394bd48c`).  I can not reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I'll try reinstalling and see what happens...

Comment: Still not working after reinstalling, unfortunately.

Comment: @Bill. Not much more I can do from here. If you're willing to put together a simple vagrant file that can reproduce the issue then I'd likely check it out, but without an ability to reproduce seems unlikely even the z3 maintainers will get anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, didn't expect you to be able to help at this point.  I'm not sure how to use Vagrant, but I'll look into it.

Comment: So it appears something was wrong with the way z3 was setup.  I just rebuilt it, and everything works perfectly now.  So I guess if you're getting a similar error, try that.  Thanks for looking at this, Thomas.